# Rear derailleur not shifting first time from lowest gear

Tags: derailleur-rear

I am installing new cables and trying to reconnect the rear derailleur. I can the gears indexed perfectly on the way up but when I try to shift down from the lowest gear (biggest cog) it doesn’t move until the 2nd click. It then shift down normally until I get I get all the way down to the last click on the shifter and it skips the second highest gear to return to the highest gear (smallest cog). Anybody have any idea what is going wrong? brand new cable which has been greased well and I have checked for snags etc and all looks ok.

Comment: have you already adjusted the indexing? (barrel adjusters and such)

Comment: Did you check the hanger alignment?

Comment: Indexing all done. The hanger alignment looks a bit off to be fair so that might be it. Is there an easy way to check? Is that a new derailleur job or can it be realigned?